# Using Image.FromFile does not release handle on a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection

I'm doing a join of multiple multi-image tiff files to a single multi-image tiff file and have a problem with deleting the source tiff files, because the Image class continues to hold the handle on them.

I'm reading a tiff image through Image.FromFile:

```
Bitmap resultTiff = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(strImageFile);
```

After which I read all other tiff images the same way and append them to the resulting tiff image.

When I finish I use this code to release references and to save resulting file:

```
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long) EncoderValue.Flush);
resultTiff.SaveAdd(ep);
resultTiff.Dispose();
```

Now the problem is that the handle on the files *still exists* (and therefore files can't be deleted) unless I call the `GC.Collect()` after the `resultTiff.Dispose()` call.

You can imagine that I don't feel very comfortable by calling GC, so is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to solve the issue with `Image.FromFile` wherein it leaves file handles open is to use `Image.FromStream` instead.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   using (Image original = Image.FromStream(fs))
   {
      ...
```

Using an explicit Dispose(), a using() statement or setting the value to null doesn't solve the issue until a garbage collection happens.  Forcing a garbage collection to happen is generally a bad idea.

Comment: +1 for this answer. `Image.FromFile` does not always do exactly the right thing. Replacing it by manually opening a file stream and then loading the bitmap from there gives you some more flexibility.

Comment: For some reason `FileStream` was still giving me the same issue. Instead I used `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))`, which worked well.

Answer (score 5):

Or try:

```
Using(Bitmap resultTiff = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(strImageFile))
{
   ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long) EncoderValue.Flush);
   resultTiff.SaveAdd(ep);
}
```

Comment: While using `using` is definitely a good recommendation, it probably won't solve Goran's particular problem. The example code given in the question already calls `Dispose` (in non-exceptional circumstances).

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. It just happened that I had a glitch somewhere else in the code, and when I fixed that using of just Dispose solved my problems.
I wasn't disposing references to the files I was _appending_ to the first file. When I corrected this, everything started working great.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
resultTiff = null;
```

Comment: ass much as you shouldnt need to do this - it works.  I had an image app that loaded 1000's of images in a loop and processed them.  if i didn't have `img = null` in the loop i would get OOM errors very quickly.

Comment: @Pondium: I've had that problem, too. As a sidenote, I suspect that it might not solely be caused caused by insufficient memory, but by a lack of GDI handles, as well.